# Laravel - Remove JSON header before saving to DB

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, laravel

I am fairly new to Laravel and Json.

I am looking to save JSON data directly to MYSQL table. Everything is working fine but this is the output I am getting which is being stored:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Content-Type:  application/json
Date:          Sun, 01 Oct 2017 04:10:34 GMT

{"_token":"53jnwIYCnLu1jeHdSVcL75Mgw2OD6RmZAh7Ojdyy","name":"adfadfdafd"}
```

I would like this to be the output saved in the db and everything else ignored:

```
{"_token":"53jnwIYCnLu1jeHdSVcL75Mgw2OD6RmZAh7Ojdyy","name":"adfadfdafd"}
```

Here is my controller:

```
public function addleads(Request $request)
    {
        $lead = new Lead;
        $lead->lead_data = response()->json($request);
        $lead->save();   
    }
```

View

```
           <!-- load jQuery -->
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

            <!-- provide the csrf token -->
            <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
            <input class="name"></input>
            <button class="postbutton">Post via ajax!</button> 
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
                    $(".postbutton").click(function(){
                        $.ajax({
                            /* the route pointing to the post function */
                            url: "{{ route('addleads') }}",
                            type: 'POST',
                            /* send the csrf-token and the input to the controller */
                            data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN, name:$(".name").val()},
                            dataType: 'JSON',
                            /* remind that 'data' is the response of the AjaxController */
                            success: function (data) { 
                                console.log(JSON.parse(data)); 
                            }
                        }); 
                    });
               });    
            </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on your code, you can use this

```
public function addleads(Request $request)
{
    $lead = new Lead;
    $lead->lead_data = response()->json($request)->getContent();
    $lead->save();   
}
```

if you are not actually want to get response json, but request json, you can call `$request->json()` or `json_encode($request->all())`

Comment: getting this error: file
:
"D:\xampp\htdocs\leadcapture\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Str.php"
line
:
334
message
:
"Object of class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag could not be converted to string"

Comment: I think, instead of `$request->json()`, you can use `$request->all()` to fetch all parmeters.

Comment: @RajaAbbas i've updated the code based on your old code, it's a symfony function

Comment: Thank You @HanlinWang you are awesome. I used the json_encode($request->all()) method.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to extract the required data from request and save, like this:

```
public function addleads(Request $request) { 
    $lead = new Lead; 
    $lead->lead_data = json_encode($request->only('_token', 'name'));
    $lead->save(); 
}
```